# Spring MVC e Ajax

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc

Estou desenvolvendo um app web em java utilizando o framework Spring MVC. Porém chegou uma parte no projeto que estou quebrando a cabeça!.

Antes vou mostrar o print da tela para facilitar o entendimento.

Imagem: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu quero fazer é o seguinte: quando o usuário selecionar a empresa, os elementos abaixo (salário, 13º salário e Informe de rendimentos) serão carregados dinamicamente. Nem todas as empresas tem todas as opções. **Obs**: Aquele botão gerar demonstrativo não existira mais.

Depois de algumas pesquisas pensei em fazer assim:

- Criar uma função em javascript para pegar a ação do select e enviar o item selecionado via ajax. Pelo que entendi, posso usar a annotation `@RequestBody` para ler o `json` enviado pelo ajax.
- Com o item selecionado em mãos, consigo passa-lo como parâmetro no select que faço no banco que traz as opções disponíveis para aquela empresa.
- com a annotation `@ResponseBody` envio um `json` com as opções e crio as tags com javascript.

Não sei se a lógica está certa, mas o problema disso tudo é que não sei fazer.

Minha dúvidas:

- Como eu recupero o item selecionado e envio para o controller do spring? Por exemplo: eu tenho um objeto empresa que tem os atributos nome e CNPJ, como pego o atributo CNPJ do item selecionado e envio para controller?
- Depois como eu devolvo para a pagina os itens disponíveis para aquela empresa?

Vejam como está o método do meu controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(Model model, 
                    @ModelAttribute("usuarioLogado") Usuario usuario,
                    Empresa empresa) {

    Funcionario funcionario = daoFuncionario.getFuncionario(usuario);
    List<Empresa> empresas = daoEmpresa.listaEmpresas(funcionario);

    model.addAttribute("empresa", empresa);
    model.addAttribute("funcionario", funcionario);
    model.addAttribute("empresas", empresas);

    return "usuario/menu";
}
```

Agora a página:

```xml
<form:form commandName="empresa" class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Olá, ${funcionario.nome}</legend>

        <!-- Select Empresa -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="empresa">Empresa </label>

            <!-- 
            <select class="form-control">
                <c:forEach items="${empresas}" var="empresa">
                    <option value="${empresa.cnpj}">
                        ${empresa.cnpjFormatado}- ${empresa.razaoSocial}
                    </option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
             -->

            <form:select path="razaoSocial" class="form-control">
                <form:options items="${empresas}" />
            </form:select>
```

Não sei também qual a melhor forma de fazer o select. Da primeira forma usando `c:forEach` ou usando a próprio select do spring.

### EDIT

Pessoal, estou conseguindo pegar o item selecionado no controller assim:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    function empresaSelecionaClick() {
        var cnpj = $("#razaoSocial option:selected" ).val();
        var json = {cnpj : cnpj}

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'menuDinamico',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(json),

            success : function(resposta){
                // pegar a lista e montar os elementos
            }
        })

        .done(function() {
            console.log("success");
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        });
    }

    $("#razaoSocial").change(empresaSelecionaClick);

});
```

Métodos no controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/menu", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ModelAndView menu(@ModelAttribute("usuarioLogado") Usuario usuario, Empresa empresa) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("usuario/menu");

    Funcionario funcionario = daoFuncionario.getFuncionario(usuario);
    mav.addObject("funcionario", funcionario);
    mav.addObject("empresa", empresa);
    mav.addObject("empresas", daoEmpresa.listaEmpresas(funcionario));

    return mav;

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/menuDinamico", method = RequestMethod.POST)
private @ResponseBody List<UltimoPeriodoAberto> listaOpcoes(@RequestBody Empresa empresa) {

    List<UltimoPeriodoAberto> opcoes = daoUltimoPeriodoAberto.getPeriodoHolerite(empresa);

    System.out.println("CNPJ empresa: " + empresa.getCnpj());

    for (UltimoPeriodoAberto ultimoPeriodoAberto : opcoes) {
        System.out.println(ultimoPeriodoAberto.getDescricao());
    }

    return opcoes;
}
```

Porém no segundo método está dando *null pointer execption* na linha:

```
List<UltimoPeriodoAberto> opcoes = daoUltimoPeriodoAberto.getPeriodoHolerite(empresa);
```

Não estou conseguindo identificar o erro.

### **EDIT**

Bom, eu consegui resolver. Fiz assim

Troquei a anotação `@RequestBody` pela `@ModelAttribute`:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/menuDinamico", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<UltimoPeriodoAberto> opcoesDinamicas(@ModelAttribute("empresa") Empresa empresa) {

    System.out.println(empresa.getCnpj());
    List<UltimoPeriodoAberto> opcoes = daoUltimoPeriodoAberto.getPeriodoHolerite(empresa);

    System.out.println(opcoes.size());

    return opcoes;
}
```

Mudei a requisição ajax também..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function empresaSelecionaClick() {
        var empresa = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'menuDinamico',
            data: empresa,
        })

        .done(function(data) {
            console.log("success");
            console.log(data)
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        });
    }
    $("#cnpj").change(empresaSelecionaClick);
});
```

Agora estou recebendo o erro `406` no ajax:

> The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers

O ajax não está conseguindo pegar a minha lista, alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: Felipe, na sua consulta você vai passar o que como parâmetro para consulta? ID, CNPJ? Espera como resultado um JSON, por exemplo? Se for, faço um exemplo para você, só me informe a versão do Spring está usando.

Comment: Estou passando como parâmetro o CNPJ. A consulta estou conseguindo fazer, acredito que meu problema está em receber o retorno da requisição ajax. Por exemplo, devo retornar uma lista de objetos, e montar as tags com os atributos. Estou usando a versão 4.1.6 do spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Da forma que você pretende usar, e a que entendi, você não precisa usar usar `@ModelAttribute`, já que não iremos enviar todo o objeto do modelo que está no form.

Como iremos passar apenas o CNPJ como parâmetro da consulta, irei considerar dois exemplos:

- recebendo o CNPJ no corpo da requisição, como JSON, no formato `{"cnpj": "11111111111"}`. O serviço para consulta atenderá em `/empresa/menudinamico`
- recebendo o CNPJ como parâmetro da URL, tendo a URL o padrão ``

Nos cenários acima, ambos retornam JSON como resposta e este é o meu HTML de teste:

```html
<select id="razaoSocial">
  <option value="0">--- Selecione</option>
  <option value="11111111111">Empresa 1</option>
  <option value="22222222222">Empresa 2</option>
</select>

<div id="options"></div>
```

OK, feito esta introdução, primeiro vou lhe mostrar como ficou o controller. Para o primeiro caso teremos isto (observe que é de forma resumida):

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/menudinamico",
    method = {GET, POST},
    consumes = APPLICATION_JSON,
    produces = APPLICATION_JSON)
public final List<UltimoPeriodoAberto> optionByRequestBody(@RequestBody final Empresa empresa) {
    LOGGER.info("CNPJ recebido: " + empresa.getCnpj());
    return this.daoUltimoPeriodoAberto.getPeriodoHolerite(empresa);
}
```

Como estamos passando um JSON no corpo da mensagem precisamos falar para o spring isto, ou seja, com isto ele vai pegar o JSON e já deserializar para o objeto.

E para o segundo, seu método deverá se parecer com isto:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/menudinamico/{cnpj}", method = GET, produces = APPLICATION_JSON)
public final List<UltimoPeriodoAberto> optionByRequestParam(@PathVariable final String cnpj) {
    LOGGER.info("CNPJ recebido: " + cnpj);
    return this.daoUltimoPeriodoAberto.getPeriodoHolerite(new Empresa(cnpj));
}
```

Neste caso, de diferente do primeiro, estamos usando [`@PathVariable`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html), que é para falara para o string "injetar" o valor de acordo com o *template* da URL informada. Foi também retirado [`@RequestBody`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html) já que não estamos enviado nada no corpo da mensagem agora, mas apenas como parâmetro na URL.

Nos dois caos usamos [`@ResponseBody`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html), ou seja, estamos falando para o spring serializar o retorno de acordo com o definido em *produces* e de acordo com o *Accept* enviado pelo cliente também. Você pode ver sobre isto detalhadamente na documentação de referência.

Para a chamada, vou considerar este trecho que você disse que já está OK para recuperar o valor do select do form, mudando apenas o corpo deles:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function empresaSelecionaClick() {
        var cnpj = $(this).val();
        var json = {cnpj: cnpj};

        // substitua aqui conforme necessário

    }

    $("#razaoSocial").change(empresaSelecionaClick);
});
```

Este para o primeiro método:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/menudinamico',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(json),
    success : function(data){
        innerOptionsInHTML(data);
    }
}).done(function() {
    console.log("success");
}).fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
});
```

Este para o segundo método:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/menudinamico/' + cnpj,
    success : function(data){
        innerOptionsInHTML(data);
    }
}).done(function() {
    console.log("success");
}).fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
});
```

Usei o CNPJ **11111111111** para o primeiro método, que me retornou isto:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "nome":"Option 1"
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "nome":"Option 2"
   }
]
```

E o CNPJ **22222222222** para o segundo método, que retorno isto:

```
[
   {
      "id":3,
      "nome":"Option 3"
   },
   {
      "id":4,
      "nome":"Option 3"
   },
   {
      "id":5,
      "nome":"Option 5"
   }
]
```

Para gerar o conteúdo no seu HTML, você pode fazer algo assim:

```js
function innerOptionsInHTML(data) {
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    var options = $("#options");
    $(options).empty();
    $.each(json, function(i, item) {
        var obj = json[i];
        $(options).append("<li id=" + obj.id + ">" + obj.nome + "</li");
    });
};
```

Após a execução do primeiro método, ele gerou esta parte no HTML para o primeiro caso (o segundo é semelhante):

```html
<ul id="options">
    <li id="1">Option 1</li>
    <li id="2">Option 2</li>
</ul>
```

**Observação**: como você está usando [`ModelAndView`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html), é importante gerar as opções dentro do form e com nome/id ao do objeto, para que o Spring posso "injetá-lo" corretamente.

**Observação 2**: estou considerando que seu ambiente está com o Spring devidamente configurado.

Comment: Cara muito obrigado. Compreendi muito bem sua explicação. Eu estava com problemas porque tinha configurado o JsonViewResolver, contentNegotiatingViewResolver e configureContentNegotiation, para retornar mais de um formato, porém não será mais necessário. Eu tinha consigo com o modelAttribute, porém nesse contexto também entendo que é melhor usar PathVariable, pois não envio o objeto todo.

Comment: @FelipeRenan legal que tenha conseguido

Answer (score 0):

Eu faria da seguinte forma:

Uma chamada `AJAX` com o evento `.change();` Ou seja, toda vez que for selecionado algum item dentro do meu *select* iria ser passada o nome da empresa ou id da mesma para o meu controller, com isso você poderia realizar a logica na sua *action* devolvendo os valores pertinentes e posteriormente montando-os na tela com o *jQuery*.

**Exemplo:**

```
<form:select id="razao-social" path="razaoSocial" class="form-control">
        <form:options items="${empresas}" />
</form:select>

$('#razao-social').change(function() {
    $.get("action/fazalgumaCoisa", {parametro: $(this).val()}, function(data) {
        //Criar a montagem da tela com o jQuery
    }).fail(function() {
        alert("Ocorreu um erro, tente novamente mais tarde.");
    });
});


    @RequestMapping(value = "action/faz-alguma-coisa", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Object retornaAlgo(Model model, 
                    @ModelAttribute("usuarioLogado") Usuario usuario,
                    Empresa empresa, @RequestParam Long parametro){
   model.addAttribute("empresa", empresa);
    model.addAttribute("funcionario", funcionario);
    model.addAttribute("empresas", empresas);
        return Object;      
    }
```

No seu caso você deve retornar algo para ser tratado com o *callback* do *Ajax*.

Comment: Opa... valeu pela sugestão. Porém tentei fazer dessa forma e não consegui. Eu até consigo pegar item selecionado e enviar para o controller, porém não consigo fazer o restante. Com o item selecionado tenho que fazer o select no banco e retornar uma lista para a pagina. Porém quando faço isso da null pointer execption. Vou editar a pergunta para facilitar o entendimento

Comment: stack do nullpionter cadê? Colocou em debug e verificou o que está sendo retornado na lista de opções?

Comment: João, adicionei a exception no post. Fiz debug sim, mais não consigo identificar o erro. Declarei os objetos com Autowired, e o engraçado é que se eu crio uma lista dentro do método "menu" e percorro não dá a exception, o mesmo código dentro dentro do outro método está dando null pointer.